# how to use custom profiles with django-registration

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'am using a custom user profile with Django 1.5 and i'am trying to use the lastest django-registration version with it but I always get an error when running the sync command.

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
registration.registrationprofile: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
```

Model:

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=254,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
    )
```

Settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'gofindwhat_app.UserProfile'
```

Comment: what is the definition of `AbstractBaseUser`? It cannot have reference to `django.contrib.auth.User`

Comment: AbstractBaseUser is new in Django 1.5 and is part of django.contrib.auth.models.

Comment: I've found a way to go around this problem by doing some changes to django-registration... but I really don't want to.

Comment: please tell me, how you solved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Olga, 1st I had to do this changes:
https://bitbucket.org/prjts/django-registration/commits/ba31fc3053bfca7eb7a19d912882e50e295adc55

2nd I had to create my own backend based on the default backend.